# How do you dynamically add a css transform with ng2

Tags: html, css, angular, css-transforms

I'm trying to set the transform based on conditions AND variables. In most cases I can dynamically set a style with all kinds of logic, such as setting the height based on view width with a function in my component:

```
<button *ngFor="let slide of slides; let i = index" [style.height.vw]="circleNavSize(i)"></button>
```

or with a formula right there in the markup:

```
<button [style.width.vw]="widthVW / slides.length - 1"></button>
```

But none of that is working with transform. Usually there is no error, it just does nothing. I tried things like this:

```
<button [style.transform]="circleNavTransform()"></button>

circleNavTransform() {
  return 'translateY(' + this.circleNavSize() + ')';
}
```

Or like this:

```
<button [style.transform.translateY]="circleNavTransform()"></button>
```

or like this:

```
<button [style.transform]="translateY(circleNavSize())"></button>
```

This last one finally returns an error since translateY is not a function...

I don't see anything in the angular.io docs.
I'm out of ideas.